# Rstudio show only the first 50 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I have a problem on RStudio in my data view, I can see only the first 50 columns for all dataframes. Is it possible to increase the number of view columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can increase the number of columns to view at a time.  But you can click the little arrow at the top to scroll across to more columns.

[image]

I'm using RStudio 1.2.1335 and not sure which version of RStudio first implemented this feature.

Comment: Thanks, @Dan Y. But I don't have this option in my RStudio version. But I didn't know that is a normal think. Thanks for the information, living and learning.

Comment: Ops, my bad. I have this option.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a "hidden" RStudio option to set the maximum number of columns the viewer will display before switching to the arrows.

This example sets the number to 1000 columns:

`rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("data_viewer_max_columns", 1000L)`

Found in an [RStudio developer's comment](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5170#issuecomment-638946249) on a [github issue about this topic](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5170).

**---EDIT---**

You can set this value in the Command Palette in RStudio v1.4:

[image]